# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" i am getting this error whenever i am running one particualar testng suite file in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, out-of-memory, testng

ours is maven project, our framework was desinged in such a way that entire project will be checkedout in to test environment[Virtual Linux Machine] and from there maven command will be executed with mentioned suite file. every thing triggerd in jenkins.

As a beginner i dont understand this particular suite is getting failed with below error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
>         at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
>         at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:372)
>         at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)

The suite file is

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test" verbose="10">
    <parameter name="component" value="run" />
    <parameter name="testtype" value="sanity" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="class" />
    </listeners>


     <test name="testa" time-out="5400000">

        <classes>
            <class name="classa " />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="testb" time-out="3600000">
    <classes>
    <class name="classb"/>
    </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="testc" >

        <classes>
            <class name="classc" />

        </classes>
        </test> 

    <test name="testd">
        <classes>
            <class name="classdd>

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

[Due to data privacy i renamed it to classa and testa]

please guide me, is their any thing i have to modify in maven options  or include in suite file, or to change anything in jenkins ? please advice me.

Comment: If you run the same test with maven outside of Jenkins, do you get the same error? I assume the class under test requires much memory, but this might be a bug in the code or intentional. That is only something you can decide. If it is intentional, you can specify how much memory the job may have using `-Xmx200m`. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Comment: if any further info required, please post as comment, i can give deatils

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge. i have added evniroment varialbles for MAVEN_OPTS as -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  and triggred job.

Comment: still my test case is blocked due to this error :( 

maven_opts = -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: This message `unable to create new native thread at ` means simple your are exceeding the limits of threads you are allowed to create. Usually you are allowed to created only 1024 threads on a linux box...Nothing to do with memory...

Comment: @khmarbaise : is their anything you can help me to increase thread count in linux machine?

Comment: This will help only temporarily cause if you have Java app which uses so much threads this sounds wrong...to me. I would try to figure out why so many threads being generated...What kind of app are we talking about..

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running out of some system resources during the test execution. This error message may appear due to file opened descriptors limit being reached or number of processes ran per user. While this is a really broad issue these links may guide you through the process of troubleshooting:

[Jenkins limits: ulimit on *nix](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204231510-Memory-problem-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-)

[Similar issue discussed in google groups](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-td4698692.html)

[Java 'unable to create new native thread' explanation](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread)